# Matplotlib: RangeSlider breaks when used from left side?

Tags: python, matplotlib, rangeslider

I am trying to create a Matplotlib figure that handles N plots with a common x axis, a Rangeslider, a Cursor and Annotations.
I am very close to making it work, but I encountered the strangest issue.

When I use the RangeSlider (only from the left side though!) the view will not resize at all; it will correctly slice the plot, but will leave a growing blank space to the left..

I noticed that deleting the Cursor from the script will actually make it work! But I would like to have both RangeSlider and Cursor working.

[See screenshot of the issue: -> blank space is left from x=1, to wherever the slider is moving, in this case x=4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgDl4.png)

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as mwidgets


analysis = pd.DataFrame({"date": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],"alfa": [50, 40, 45, 30, 20, 15],"beta": [10, 20, 40, 50, 55, 70]})

# create figure and axes for data plotting
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 10))
ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel='alfa')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel(ylabel='beta')

# data plotting
def plot(data):
    line1,=ax1.plot(data["date"], data["alfa"], label='alfa')
    line2,=ax2.plot(data["date"], data["beta"], color='g', label='beta')
    ax2.legend(handles=[line1, line2])

plot(analysis)

# create axes for cursor and annotations
ax3 = ax1.twinx()
ax3.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', left=False, right=False, labelleft=False, labelright=False)
annot = ax3.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(5, 6), textcoords='offset points', xycoords='data')
annot.set_visible(False)

cursor = mwidgets.Cursor(ax3, useblit=True, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color="#5c5c5c", linewidth=0.5)

# create axes for slider
fig1.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
ax4 = fig1.add_axes([0.3, 0.15, 0.4, 0.02])
ax4.set_ylabel(ylabel='slider')
slider = mwidgets.RangeSlider(ax=ax4,label='',valmin=1,valmax=6,valinit=(1,6))

# update annotation
def update_annot(x, y):
    text = str(x),',',str(y)
    annot.xy = (x,y)
    annot.set_text(''.join(text))
    print('---')

def onclick_get_coordinates(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax3:
        update_annot(event.xdata, event.ydata)
        annot.set_visible(True)
        fig1.canvas.draw_idle()
    else:
        if vis:
            annot.set_visible(False)
            fig1.canvas.draw_idle()
fig1.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", onclick_get_coordinates)

# update slider
def update_slider(val):
    newData = analysis[(analysis["date"] >= int(val[0])) & (analysis["date"] <= int(val[1]))]
    ax1.cla()
    ax2.cla()

    plot(newData)  # draw the new graph
    fig1.canvas.draw_idle()  # allow the graph to be changed again
slider.on_changed(update_slider)

# show plot
plt.show()
```

Grateful to anyone who can guide me through the darkness :)

Other than deleting Cursor, I also tried tinkering with Axes.zorder and/or assigning Cursor and Annotation to different 'support axes', but to no avail.